# pandas dtype conversion from object to string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file that has a few columns which are numbers and few that are string. When I try `myDF.dtypes` it shows me all the string columns as `object`.

1. Someone asked a related question before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018654/strings-in-a-dataframe-but-dtype-is-object) about why this is done. Is it possible to recast the `dtype` from object to string?
2. Also, in general, is there any easy way to recast the `dtype` from `int64` and `float64` to `int32` and `float32` and save on the size of the data (in memory / on disk)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All strings are represented as variable-length (which is what `object` dtype is holding). You can do `series.astype('S32')` if you want; but it will be recast if you then store it in a DataFrame or do much with it. This is for simplicity.

Certain serialization formats, e.g. `HDFStore` stores the strings as fixed-length strings on disk though.

You can `series.astype(int32)` if you would like and it will store as the new type.

Comment: Just to be clear you recommend changing *each* series in a data frame before saving it via HDFstore and vice versa when loading?

Comment: you can create a pandas object of a specific dtype if u want or astype later. not sure what your goal is; why do you care what string dtype it actually is; why is object a problem?

Comment: @Jeff I have written a function, it's giving null as output because it doesn't see str fromat it sees object format
what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

```
df = your dataframe object with values
print('dtype in object form :')
print(df.dtypes[df.columns[0]])    // output: dtype('O')
print('\ndtype in string')
print(str(df.dtypes[df.columns[0]]))    // output: 'object'
```