# Pandas aggregating average while excluding current row

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

How to aggregate in the way to get the average of `b` for group `a`, while excluding the current row (the target result is in `c`)?

```
a b   c

1 1   0.5   # (avg of 0 & 1, excluding 1)
1 1   0.5   # (avg of 0 & 1, excluding 1)
1 0   1     # (avg of 1 & 1, excluding 0)

2 1   0.5   # (avg of 0 & 1, excluding 1)
2 0   1     # (avg of 1 & 1, excluding 0)
2 1   0.5   # (avg of 0 & 1, excluding 1)

3 1   0.5   # (avg of 0 & 1, excluding 1)
3 0   1     # (avg of 1 & 1, excluding 0)
3 1   0.5   # (avg of 0 & 1, excluding 1)
```

Data dump:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1, 0.5], [1, 1, 0.5], [1, 0, 1], [2, 1, 0.5], [2, 0, 1], 
                     [2, 1, 0.5], [3, 1, 0.5], [3, 0, 1], [3, 1, 0.5]],
                     columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suppose a group has values `x_1, ..., x_n`.

The average of the entire group would be

```
m = (x_1 + ... + x_n)/n
```

The sum of the group without `x_i` would be

```
(m*n - x_i)
```

The average of the group without `x_i` would be

```
(m*n - x_i)/(n-1)
```

Therefore, you could compute the desired column of values with

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1, 0.5], [1, 1, 0.5], [1, 0, 1], [2, 1, 0.5], [2, 0, 1], 
                     [2, 1, 0.5], [3, 1, 0.5], [3, 0, 1], [3, 1, 0.5]],
                     columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

grouped = df.groupby(['a'])
n = grouped['b'].transform('count')
mean = grouped['b'].transform('mean')
df['result'] = (mean*n - df['b'])/(n-1)
```

which yields

```
In [32]: df
Out[32]: 
   a  b    c  result
0  1  1  0.5     0.5
1  1  1  0.5     0.5
2  1  0  1.0     1.0
3  2  1  0.5     0.5
4  2  0  1.0     1.0
5  2  1  0.5     0.5
6  3  1  0.5     0.5
7  3  0  1.0     1.0
8  3  1  0.5     0.5

In [33]: assert df['result'].equals(df['c'])
```

---

Per the comments below, in the OP's actual use case, the DataFrame's `a` column
contains strings:

```
def make_random_str_array(letters, strlen, size):
    return (np.random.choice(list(letters), size*strlen)
            .view('|S{}'.format(strlen)))

N = 3*10**6
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':make_random_str_array(letters='ABCD', strlen=10, size=N),
                   'b':np.random.randint(10, size=N)})
```

so that there are about a million unique values in `df['a']` out of 3 million
total:

```
In [87]: uniq, key = np.unique(df['a'], return_inverse=True)
In [88]: len(uniq)
Out[88]: 988337

In [89]: len(df)
Out[89]: 3000000
```

In this case the calculation above requires (on my machine) about **11 seconds**:

```
In [86]: %%timeit
   ....: grouped = df.groupby(['a'])
n = grouped['b'].transform('count')
mean = grouped['b'].transform('mean')
df['result'] = (mean*n - df['b'])/(n-1)
   ....:    ....:    ....:    ....: 
1 loops, best of 3: 10.5 s per loop
```

[Pandas converts all string-valued columns to `object`
dtype](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21841473/190597). But we could convert the
DataFrame column to a NumPy array with a fixed-width dtype, and the group
according to those values.

Here is a benchmark showing that if we convert the Series with object dtype to a NumPy array with fixed-width string dtype, the calculation requires less than **2 seconds**:

```
In [97]: %%timeit
   ....: grouped = df.groupby(df['a'].values.astype('|S4'))
n = grouped['b'].transform('count')
mean = grouped['b'].transform('mean')
df['result'] = (mean*n - df['b'])/(n-1)
   ....:    ....:    ....:    ....: 
1 loops, best of 3: 1.39 s per loop
```

Beware that you need to know the maximum length of the strings in `df['a']` to choose the appropriate fixed-width dtype. In the example above, all the strings have length 4, so `|S4` works. If you use `|Sn` for some integer `n` and `n` is smaller than the longest string, then those strings will get silently truncated with no error warning. This could potentially lead to the grouping of values which should not be grouped together. Thus, the onus is on you to choose the correct fixed-width dtype.

You could use

```
dtype = '|S{}'.format(df['a'].str.len().max())
grouped = df.groupby(df['a'].values.astype(dtype))
```

to ensure the conversion uses the correct dtype.

Comment: Also, what would happen if there is only 1 case? I'd like to make that the average of all the other cases that do not fail.

Comment: So replace afterwards.

Comment: It's incredibly slow though (4 million rows). I'm thinking perhaps the better way is to just aggregate including the row, and then subtract, weighted by counts (your first comment helped with the idea)?

Comment: There is something different about your real use case that I'm not seeing. I've run the code above with `df = pd.concat([df]*1000000)` so that `len(df)` is 9 million, and `%timeit df.groupby(['a'])['b'].transform(ave_others)` completes in 1.18 seconds.

Comment: Perhaps to do with the amount of unique groups? There are 1 million out of 3 million unique groups.

Comment: Yes, I was experimenting with that just now. With `df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10000, size=(N,2)), columns=['a','b'])`, with `N = 10**6`, I'm still getting `%timeit df.groupby(['a'])['b'].transform(ave_others)` to complete in 2.96 seconds.

Comment: Absurd: when I do the exact same thing with a different 'groupby' variable, it also takes me 2.5 seconds.

Comment: What is the dtype of the problematic column? You can find the dtypes with `df.info()`.

Comment: That was the first thing I checked afterwards: both are `dtype=object`

Comment: With `dtype=object`, grouping requires equality checking of the Python objects. This will be much slower than grouping when the dtype is a native NumPy dtype.

Comment: I could cast them as `str`, would that improve the speed?

Comment: Yes, I believe converting the strings to a fixed-width dtype can improve speed. 
Since [Pandas converts all string-valued columns to `object` dtype](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21841473/190597), you can not store the fixed-width NumPy array in the DataFrame itself. But you can still use that NumPy array as the values by which to groupby: `grouped = df.groupby(df['a'].values.astype('|S4'))`. I've edited the post above to show some benchmarks.

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate the statistics manually by iterating group by group:

```
# Set up input
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([
        [1, 1, 0.5], [1, 1, 0.5], [1, 0, 1], 
        [2, 1, 0.5], [2, 0, 1], [2, 1, 0.5], 
        [3, 1, 0.5], [3, 0, 1], [3, 1, 0.5]
    ], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
df
   a  b    c
0  1  1  0.5
1  1  1  0.5
2  1  0  1.0
3  2  1  0.5
4  2  0  1.0
5  2  1  0.5
6  3  1  0.5
7  3  0  1.0
8  3  1  0.5

# Perform grouping, excluding the current row
results = []
grouped = df.groupby(['a'])
for key, group in grouped:
    for idx, row in group.iterrows():
        # The group excluding current row
        group_other = group.drop(idx)  
        avg = group_other['b'].mean()
        results.append(row.tolist() + [avg])

# Compare our results with what is expected
results_df = pd.DataFrame(
    results, columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'c_new']
)
results_df
   a  b    c  c_new
0  1  1  0.5    0.5
1  1  1  0.5    0.5
2  1  0  1.0    1.0
3  2  1  0.5    0.5
4  2  0  1.0    1.0
5  2  1  0.5    0.5
6  3  1  0.5    0.5
7  3  0  1.0    1.0
8  3  1  0.5    0.5
```

This way you can use any statistic you want.