# Groupby and find mean of a column rowwise subsetting that row python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem in python. This is my sample data

```
     col1  col2  desired
0    a     1     2.50
1    a     2     2.00
2    a     3     1.50
3    b     2     3.00
4    b     3     2.00
5    c     3     1.67
6    c     1     2.33
7    c     2     2.00
8    c     2     2.00
```

the input are `df['col1']` and `df['col2']`. I want to use these two columns to produce the desired outcome in `df['desired']`.

The idea is, that I want to group by `col1` and calculate the average value of `col2`. The only tweak here, though, is that I want to exclude the current row from the average value calculation.

So for row 0, I am grouping by `df['col1'] == 'a'`, but only use row 1 and 2 to calculate the average. For row 1, I also group by `df['col1'] == 'a'`, but I only use row 1 and 3. And so forth.

The only thing I can think of, is to create a custom function for `.transform()` that will take as input the series coming in from the grouped object, but I am not sure how to approach it. Ideally, I am looking for a simpler (pandas?) method to achieve this.

Comment: Text version of the data please.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you're asking

Comment: Unclear question ..

Comment: saw the edit. yes that example is precisely what i meant. corresponding to each row basically subset it from the grouped mean calculation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30274561/pandas-aggregating-average-while-excluding-current-row

Comment: had not found the above one. must have been using the wrong key words. but yes this is a duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution working with definition of `mean` - `sum/count`.

So first get count by [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and subtract 1 for remove actual row, same with `sum` for remove actual row value. Last divide and assign to new column:

```
a = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].transform('size').sub(1)
b = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].transform('sum').sub(df['col2'])

df['des'] = b / a
print (df)
  col1  col2  desired       des
0    a     1     2.50  2.500000
1    a     2     2.00  2.000000
2    a     3     1.50  1.500000
3    b     2     3.00  3.000000
4    b     3     2.00  2.000000
5    c     3     1.67  1.666667
6    c     1     2.33  2.333333
7    c     2     2.00  2.000000
8    c     2     2.00  2.000000
```

Comment: more concise than the answer in the duplicate question. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is filtering the selected row:

```
df['desired'] = df.apply(lambda x: df[~df.index.isin([x.name])].groupby('col1')['col2'].mean().loc[x['col1']], axis=1)
```

output:

```
>>0    2.5
1    2.0
2    1.5
3    5.5
4    5.0
5    4.5
```