# Pandas: Calculate mean leaving out own row's value

Tags: python, pandas, mean, aggregation

I want to calculate means by group, leaving out the value of the row itself.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'col1': ["a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a"], 'col2': [0, 4, 3, -5, 3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I know how to return means by group:

```
df.groupby('col1').agg({'col2': 'mean'})
```

Which returns:

```
Out[247]: 
  col1  col2
1    a     4
3    a    -5
5    a     4
```

But what I want is mean by group, leaving out the row's value. E.g. for the first row:

```
df.query('col1 == "a"')[1:4].mean()
```

which returns:

```
Out[251]: 
col2    1.0
dtype: float64
```

*Edit:*
Expected output is a dataframe of the same format as `df` above, with a column `mean_excl_own` which is the mean across all other members in the group, excluding the row's own value.

Comment: `df.groupby('col1').mean()`

Comment: check this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30274561/pandas-aggregating-average-while-excluding-current-row

Answer (score 1):

You could [`GroupBy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) `col1`and [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) with the mean. Then subtract the value from a given row from the mean:

```
df['col2'] = df.groupby('col1').col2.transform('mean').sub(df.col2)
```

Comment: I think the OP wants the aggregated mean of the group rather than this

Comment: But he wants to subtract the value from a given row, that would only make sense if the row itself is included in the solution right?

Comment: They want to calculate mean for the entire group, but ignore the first row for that group, at least this was my understanding, I could be wrong of course

Comment: Hmm actually I think you're right, I'll delete my answer

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all your input. I ended up using the approach linked to by @VnC.

Here's how I solved it:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'col1': ["a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a"], 'col2': [0, 4, 3, -5, 3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

group_summary = df.groupby('col1', as_index=False)['col2'].agg(['mean', 'count'])
df = pd.merge(df, group_summary, on = 'col1')

df['other_sum'] = df['col2'] * df['mean'] - df['col2'] 
df['result'] = df['other_sum'] / (df['count']  - 1)
```

Check out the final result:

```
df['result']
```

Which prints:

```
Out: 
0    1.000000
1   -0.333333
2    2.666667
3   -0.333333
4    3.000000
5    3.000000
Name: result, dtype: float64
```

*Edit:* I previously had some trouble with column names, but I fixed it using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55717100/strange-column-names-in-dataframe-after-joining-dataframe-on-summary-of-itself/55717155#55717155) answer.