# Divide a row by the mean of all other rows with the same datetime

Tags: python, pandas

I have this `pandas` `DataFrame`

```
                              val
datetime   attribute_id          
2018-01-31 0             4.162565
           1             3.305480
           2             3.191123
           3             3.601398
           4             3.277375
           6             3.556552
2018-02-28 0             0.593762
           1             0.594565
           2             0.583355
           3             0.611113
           4             0.577600
           6             0.638904
```

And I would like to have a column `ratio` where for each month each attribute is divided by the mean of all other attributes.

For example, for `datetime` = 2018-01-31, which refers to the month of January,  I would like the column `ratio` to contain the value of attribute 0 (4.162565) divided by the mean of attributes 1,2,3,4 and 6 which is the mean of 3.305480, 3.191123, 3.601398, 3.277375 and 3.556552. This month-wise for each attribute.

`datetime` and `attribute_id` are a `MultiIndex`.

Does someone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count mean per first MultiIndex level with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and create new Series with same size like original DataFrame and dnen divide column by [`Series.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.div.html):

```
print (df.groupby(level=0)['val'].transform('mean'))
datetime    attribute_id
2018-01-31  0               3.515749
            1               3.515749
            2               3.515749
            3               3.515749
            4               3.515749
            6               3.515749
2018-02-28  0               0.599883
            1               0.599883
            2               0.599883
            3               0.599883
            4               0.599883
            6               0.599883
Name: val, dtype: float64

df['result'] = df['val'].div(df.groupby(level=0)['val'].transform('mean'))
print (df)
                              val    result
datetime   attribute_id                    
2018-01-31 0             4.162565  1.183977
           1             3.305480  0.940192
           2             3.191123  0.907665
           3             3.601398  1.024362
           4             3.277375  0.932198
           6             3.556552  1.011606
2018-02-28 0             0.593762  0.989796
           1             0.594565  0.991135
           2             0.583355  0.972448
           3             0.611113  1.018720
           4             0.577600  0.962854
           6             0.638904  1.065047
```

---

If need exlude correct row only change `groupby(level=0)` in this [unutbu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30274639) solution:

```
grouped = df.groupby(level=0)
n = grouped['val'].transform('count')
mean = grouped['val'].transform('mean')
df['ratio'] = df['val'] / ((mean*n - df['val']) / (n-1))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer, but I don't want to divide by the mean of all attributes in the given month, but each attribute should by divided by the mean of all *others*. For example attribute 0  should be divided by the mean of attributes 1,2,3,4 and 6

Comment: Thanks! Just change the last line of code to `df['ratio'] = df['val'] / ((mean*n - df['val']) / (n-1))` to give the correct result (I wanted the row divided by the mean and with your code you just get the mean)

Comment: @Marco - Answer was changed.