# Pandas preserve fixed-length char field in structured ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a numpy structured array with dtype that looks something like this:

```
In [20]: rectype = np.dtype([
   ....:         ('id',   '<i4'), # int
   ....:         ('price','<f4'), # float
   ....:         ('flag', 'a1'),  # char
   ....:         ('n',    'u1'),  # unsigned char
   ....:         ('r',    'i2'),  # short
   ....:         ('name', 'a4')   # char[4]
   ....:     ])
```

I'd like to process with pandas and then get back a modified ndarray to be loaded into memory on an embedded device.  [As has been mentioned here already](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21020411/519015), pandas changes the dtype of the char types to `object`, so the resulting array is not compatible with the input:

```
In [21]: nda = np.fromiter([(1, 14.6, 'a', 0, 1, 'car')], dtype=rectype)
In [22]: a2 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(nda).to_records(index=False)
In [23]: a2.dtype
Out[23]: dtype([('id', '<i4'), ('price', '<f4'), ('flag', 'O'), ('n', 'u1'), ('r', '<i2'), ('name', 'O')])
In [24]: rectype.itemsize, a2.dtype.itemsize
Out[24]: (16, 27)
```

This is of course not very useful.  In my case, the length of the string *is fixed* and I need it that way to fit it into the data structure.  Is there any simple, efficient way to get back an array with the exact same data structure/dtype as that with which I started?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

call `astype()`:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_records(nda).to_records(index=False).astype(rectype)
```

Comment: Thanks!  When you phrase it that way it's really a numpy question.  This is a satisfactory solution. Still, I would have thought that a pandas round-trip should be an identity transformation.