# How to convert column with dtype as object to string in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

When I read a csv file to pandas dataframe, each column is cast to its own datatypes. I have a column that was converted to an object. I want to perform string operations for this column such as splitting the values and creating a list. But no such operation is possible because its dtype is object. Can anyone please let me know the way to convert all the items of a column to strings instead of objects?

I tried several ways but nothing worked. I used astype, str(), to_string etc.

```
a=lambda x: str(x).split(',')
df['column'].apply(a)
```

## or

```
df['column'].astype(str)
```

Comment: Sometimes, string operations fail when there are unrecognized characters present. Paste your data into notepad and see if there is weird symbols where a blank space (or something else) is expected.

Comment: everything here is outdated, answer in duplicate question:  `df['id'] = df['id'].astype("string")`

Comment: @AJAJ answer is the only one that turns object to strings, however, it turns it to string[python], dunno if that implicates something else than just "string".

Answer (score 79):

since strings data types have variable length, it is by default stored as object dtype. If you want to store them as string type, you can do something like this.

```
df['column'] = df['column'].astype('|S80') #where the max length is set at 80 bytes,
```

or alternatively

```
df['column'] = df['column'].astype('|S') # which will by default set the length to the max len it encounters
```

Comment: which python version are you using? it does not work for me

Comment: got `TypeError: data type "bytes256" not understood`, any suggestion why?

Comment: Since `pandas` inherits almost the entire `numpy`'s type system (apart from `category`) please refer to https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.scalars.html#built-in-scalar-types for more information about type shortcuts.

Comment: Works in Python 3.8.2

Comment: this ends with an error with non-latin characters for me (like `á`)

Answer (score 59):

Did you try assigning it back to the column?

```
df['column'] = df['column'].astype('str')
```

Referring to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21018654/3231320), the pandas dataframe stores the pointers to the strings and hence it is of type 
'object'. As per the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html) ,You could try:

```
df['column_new'] = df['column'].str.split(',')
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that. The datatype of that column remained as object even after trying that.

Comment: could you paste a sample of your dataframe?

Comment: I have edited the answer, please check if it works

Comment: Both of them dont work :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018654/strings-in-a-dataframe-but-dtype-is-object

Answer (score 35):

Not answering the question directly, but it might help someone else.

I have a column called `Volume`, having both `-` (invalid/NaN) and numbers formatted with `,`

```
df['Volume'] = df['Volume'].astype('str')
df['Volume'] = df['Volume'].str.replace(',', '')
df['Volume'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Volume'], errors='coerce')
```

**Casting to string is required** for it to apply to [str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)

[pandas.Series.str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)
[pandas.to_numeric](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html)

Answer (score 6):

You could try using `df['column'].str.` and then use any string function. Pandas documentation includes those like [split](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html)

Comment: Nope, pandas will store the pointer to the string and the final column type will be 'object'

Comment: I believe pandas will ALWAYS store string columns as objects