# Pandas Dataframe Issue Converting Column dtype

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a simple pandas dataframe with a column:

```
col = [['A']]
data = [[1.0],[2.3],[3.4]]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data, columns=col)
```

This creates a dataframe with one column of type `np.float64`, which is what I want.

Later in the process, I want to add another column of type `string`.

```
df['SOMETEXT'] = "SOME TEXT FOR ANALYSIS"
```

The dtype of this column is coming though as dtype of `object`, but I need it to be type `string`.  So I do the following:

```
df['SOMETEXT'] = df['SOMETEXT'].astype(str)
```

If I look at the dtype again, I get the same dtype for that column: `object`.

I have a process down my workflow that is dtype sensitive and I need the column to be a `string`.

Any ideas?

```
array = df.to_records(index=False) # convert to numpy array
```

The dtypes on the array still carry the `object` dtype, but the columns should be a `string`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert column with dtype as object to string in Pandas Dataframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33957720/how-to-convert-column-with-dtype-as-object-to-string-in-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: @languitar the solution provided did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In pandas, all strings are `object` type. It confused me too when I first started.

Once in NumPy, you can cast the string:

```
In [24]: array['SOMETEXT'].astype(str)
Out[24]: 
array(['SOME TEXT FOR ANALYSIS', 'SOME TEXT FOR ANALYSIS',
       'SOME TEXT FOR ANALYSIS'], 
      dtype='<U22')
```

Comment: ya, but when you export the DF to an numpy array, it carries the object type and doesn't convert the data to a string.

Comment: i forgot a piece of information, please see the updated question.

Comment: That's just the internal implementation. Have a look at one of the answers of the potential duplicate for an explanation.

Comment: It won't work, as this is not intended. There is an explanation why this is of type object for strings.