# filtering using columns of different types

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, filtering

I'm new to python and I 'm struggling with filtering.
I'm running the following in python:

`DataFrame[(DataFrame.column1<2 & DataFrame.column2=='text')]`

and the error I get is

```
cannot compare a dtyped [object] array with a scalar of type [bool]
```

Column1 is a float64 type and column2 is object.
The filter must be a combination of both of them.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you explain more about the data in column 1 and column 2. I am not sure what are you trying to compare between a float and string.

Answer (score 1):

`pd.DataFrame.__getitem__`, or the equivalent syntax `df[]`, does not permit Boolean indexing. Instead, you should use [`pd.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html). In addition, you should surround each condition with parentheses to avoid chained comparisons. For example:

```
mask = (df['column1'] < 2) & (df['column2'] == 'text')
df = df.loc[mask]
```

Note also you shouldn't name your dataframe `DataFrame`, this would shadow a class name.

For `object` dtype, note Pandas doesn't have a `str` dtype, these objects are stored in `object` dtype series. See also [How to convert column with dtype as object to string in Pandas Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33957720/how-to-convert-column-with-dtype-as-object-to-string-in-pandas-dataframe). You shouldn't need to apply any conversion, and if you do, you can use `df['column2'].astype(str) == 'text'`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a short example of the syntax you should use

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
# filling both columns with data

df[(df['column1']<2) & (df['column2']=='text')]
```

Comment: You can select this answer as the right one (press on the tick =)