# Python:Pandas - Object to string type conversion in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, type-conversion, tostring

I'm trying to convert object to string in my dataframe using pandas.
Having following data:

```
particulars
NWCLG 545627 ASDASD KJKJKJ ASDASD
TGS/ASDWWR42045645010009 2897/SDFSDFGHGWEWER
dtype:object
```

while trying to convert particulars column from **object to string** using **astype()[with str, |S, |S32, |S80] types**, or directly **using str functions** it is not converting in string (remain object) and for **str methods[replacing '/' with ' ']** it says `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'`

using pandas 0.23.4

Also refereed: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/18796

Comment: Did you tried like `df[`col1`].astype(str)`

Comment: yes, I tried, it remains object

Comment: Can you show us a sample of the raw data and the command you're using to convert it to a pandas dataframe?

Comment: @ParvBanks Actually I'm reading that data from excel sheet but can't put sample here as it's confidential

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert column with dtype as object to string in Pandas Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33957720/how-to-convert-column-with-dtype-as-object-to-string-in-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Try df[col1].astype("string") , it worked for me

Answer (score 4):

Use `astype('string')` instead of `astype(str)` :

```
df['column'] = df['column'].astype('string')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could read the excel specifying the `dtype` as `str`:

```
df = pd.read_excel("Excelfile.xlsx", dtype=str)
```

then **use string replace in `particulars` column as below:**

```
df['particulars'] = df[df['particulars'].str.replace('/','')]
```

**Notice that the df assignment is also a dataframe in '[]' brackets.**

When you're using the below command in your program, it returns a string which you're trying to assign to a dataframe column. Hence the error.

```
df['particulars'] = df['particulars'].str.replace('/',' ')
```

Comment: No luck still getting AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'