# Separating out rows based on int or string when column type is object

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset and one of the columns contains integers for some rows and strings for other rows.
The column type is object.

e.g:

```
Index     Column of interest
1         21678849
2         37464859
3         barbara
4         28394821
5         francis
```

I can't force the column to change type using .astype('str'). And I am unable to use .isstring, .isdigit, or .isinstance.
I've tried looking at [solutions for converting on objects to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33957720/how-to-convert-column-with-dtype-as-object-to-string-in-pandas-dataframe) but these don't seem to work.

I've also tried:

```
[True if x.isin([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]) else False for x in df['column_of_interest']]
```

But that just gives me: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isin'

Anyone have any other ideas of how I can manage this?

Ideally I would like to create a third column that categorises whether the row is an int or a str.

Comment: you can use `pd.to_numeric(df['Column of interest'],errors='coerce')` will force your strings into nulls.

Comment: So this could also work. I would then just need to add another step to make the column that identifies whether something is int or Null.

Comment: you could chain it into one, `df['DataType'] = np.where(pd.to_numeric(df['Column of interest'],errors='coerce').isnull(), 'Text','Number')` lots of ways to do this, pandas has built in datatypes you could always leverage those too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this works and I tested it:

```
import pandas as pd

#----------------------------------------
# Prepare the data in df.
#----------------------------------------

from io import StringIO

TESTDATA = StringIO("""Index;column_of_interest
1;21678849
2;37464859
3;barbara
4;28394821
5;francis""")

df = pd.read_csv(TESTDATA, sep=";")

#----------------------------------------
# The actual code to solve the problem.
#----------------------------------------

def is_integer(x):
    try:
        int(x)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

print([is_integer(x) for x in df['column_of_interest']])
```

Output is

```
[True, True, False, True, False]
```

Of course some of the code doesn't apply to you, but I wanted a full working example which I (and others) could actually test. I assume you can pick out what you need from it.

The code to test for integerness was taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1267145/1629102.

And finally code that adds the data as a new column:

```
import pandas as pd

#----------------------------------------
# Prepare the data in df.
#----------------------------------------

from io import StringIO

TESTDATA = StringIO("""Index;column_of_interest
1;21678849
2;37464859
3;barbara
4;28394821
5;francis""")

df = pd.read_csv(TESTDATA, sep=";")

#----------------------------------------
# The actual code to solve the problem.
#----------------------------------------

def is_integer(x):
    try:
        int(x)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

is_integer_list = [is_integer(x) for x in df['column_of_interest']]

df["Is_integer"] = is_integer_list

print(df)
```

with this output:

```
   Index column_of_interest  Is_integer
0      1           21678849        True
1      2           37464859        True
2      3            barbara       False
3      4           28394821        True
4      5            francis       False
```

Comment: You're welcome, Jameson! And thanks for prompting me to learn a little bit about pandas!  I heard it mentioned many times, but this was my first time actually trying it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try is `instance`:

```
[isinstance(x, int) for x in df['column_of_interest']]
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, all the values come out as False. It seems the dtype is stuck in some limbo.

Comment: @Jameson do `df.to_dict()` and paste the output instead of your data. It's hard to tell which is text which is not.

Comment: Sorry the reason I couldn't share the actual df is because there was a lot of personal information on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
[True if x in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0] else False for x in df['column_of_interest']]
```

Comment: Ok, so the code worked. Thank you! Unfortunately, the output are all False values.

Comment: That code does not work. It tests whether x is a single digit number, i.e. betwen 0 and 9. x.is_integer() likely works better, cf. my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I admit I don't know pandas, but from reading about it I boldly suggest using

```
x.is_integer()
```

instead of

```
x.isin([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0])
```

So the code would be

```
[x.is_integer() for x in df['column_of_interest']]
```

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but it doesn't work. The error is "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'is_integer'".

Comment: Ah, x is a string (type str). Then you could check whether it is an integer with `bool(re.match(r"^\d+$", x))` and `import re` earlier in the code.

Comment: Well, maybe I should just back out, as I don't know enough about pandas and shouldn't suggest too much that turns out not to work!

Comment: Okay, I didn't give up after all. Instead I read further about pandas and came up with an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64265784/1629102) that I actually tested and actually works.

Comment: Hahahah I love the enthusiasm!