# Combining date and time in object data type in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, object

I am new to python and ne of my data sets has date and time in separate columns. both are in bject type. So I tried to combine them into datetime format through the below line

```
df1.loc[:,'date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1.date.astype(object) + ' ' + df1.time.astype(object))
```

It gives me an error
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

I understand that data is in object type so + operator is not able to combine them but I am not sure how to combine object type to date time. Any help to do the same would be great.
Thanks

Comment: tried `.astype(str)`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to convert the two objects type to string,

[How to convert column with dtype as object to string in Pandas Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33957720/how-to-convert-column-with-dtype-as-object-to-string-in-pandas-dataframe)

and then concatenate the two strings and then apply pd.to_datetime()