# Fit to ML could not convert string to float

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am interested in performing machine learning by using SKLEARN
To any database
I am interested in matching the quantity to all the existing data.

Of course most of the data is not pure and there is a MIX of numbers and letters,
And the data are mostly categorical

I would love an idea of why this does not work, and how it can be used to match the quantity and / or customer to the rest of the data

I would love recommendations

**It is important to note - most of the entries are not numeric and they should indicate a serial number, ID cards, a category number, part numbers, etc.**

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
```

```
y = df['CatID']
x = df.drop(columns=["CreateDate",'DestDate',"CatID"])
X = x.values
Y = y.values
```

```
lin_reg = LinearRegression()
lin_reg.fit(X,Y)    # error line
```

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'R17'

[image]

[image]

**edit**

After I `LabelEncoder` by SKLEARN
I cant convert Object to STR

```
8   U1TypeID        14099 non-null  float64       
9   CatID           14099 non-null  object   <-----       
10  CurrencyID      14099 non-null  int64         
12  RowNumber       14099 non-null  int64         
15  SellerID        14099 non-null  object  /<----      
16  AgentID         14099 non-null  float64    

   
df[['CatID']] = str(df[['CatID']])
df['CatID'].str
df['CatID'] = df['CatID'].astype(str)
```

Its not convert to string!

Answer (score 1):

The column "sellerId" is a string and linearReg or any kind of ML accepts only integer/float variable (they don't understand string variable).
 so you should transform the "sellerId" column before feeding the data to your ML model. I suggest that you

1. transform it by using [LabelEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) from scikit-learn. 
   Or
2. you can extract the numbers from the column for example 'R17' => 17 by applying the lambda function to your column: 
   `df['sellerId'] = df['sellerId'].apply(lambda x: int(x[1:]))`

Comment: thank you so much-now i need convert object to string

Comment: You're welcome, to convert a column from object to string use this method df['column'] = df['column'].astype('str')

Comment: You should convert your columns from object => str as the first step and then apply the transformation, not the inverse.  check this link if you have a problem with converting your columns from object to str https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33957720/how-to-convert-column-with-dtype-as-object-to-string-in-pandas-dataframe