# Pandas DataFrame saved as HDF5 Files are extremely large when containing a column with a string values

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

When I create a pandas DataFrame with a column that contains a string and save it as HDF5 the file size seems extremely large. The following code processes a file with a size of **1’063’224 Bytes**.

```py
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

data_frame = pd.DataFrame({'foo': ['bar']})
data_frame.to_hdf(Path.home() / 'Desktop' / 'file.hdf5', key='baz', mode='w')
```

When I replace the `'bar'` with a `1` the file size shrinks down to **7’032 Bytes**, which seems (more) reasonable.

Does anyone know where that megabyte of data comes from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the dataframe is of dtype `object`, since [strings have variable length](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44710678/4166745) that is not [permitted in HDF5](https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/strings.html#storing-strings).

The column can be converted to string with a length parameter:

```
data_frame['foo'] = data_frame['foo'].astype('|S80') #where the max length is set at 80 bytes
```

Using this conversion, the file is even smaller than the integer example with 7024 Bytes ?!

Comment: Compare the file schema between the 2 files and you will see why the table format is more compact. The default schema creates multiple datasets for each dataframe, so requires a lot more storage space.OTOH, the table format is simpler and more efficient.