# Can not coerce an object column to string type in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column that *should* have been "born" as type `str`. But given it was not -but rather as `object`, how in the world can I get it to be of type `str` ?  i've tried a few approaches, which had been documented as supposed to work  especially here [How to convert column with dtype as object to string in Pandas Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33957720/how-to-convert-column-with-dtype-as-object-to-string-in-pandas-dataframe)

Given a dataframe `dfm` and a list of feature values `feats`

```
            # this should work as str's but does not
            dfm.insert(colx,'top20pct_features', [str(x) for x in feats])

            # let's try another way.. but also does not work
            dfm.top20pct_features = dfm.top20pct_features.astype(str)

            # another way.. same story..
            dfm.top20pct_features = dfm.top20pct_features.str
            print(dfm.info())  # reports the column as `object`
```

Comment: `string` is obviously `object`, if need dtype `string` use `df['top20pct_features'] = df['top20pct_features'].astype('string')`

Comment: Duplicate explain why get `object` for string column created by `.astype(str)
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`convert_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes.html) to benefit from the relatively recent string dtype:

```
df['top20pct_features'] = df['top20pct_features'].convert_dtypes()
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'top20pct_features': ['A', 'B', 'C']})

df.dtypes
top20pct_features    object
dtype: object

df['top20pct_features'] = df['top20pct_features'].convert_dtypes()

df.dtypes
top20pct_features    string
dtype: object
```