# pandas fail to infer str type with double quotation marks

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I want to import data from a csv file by `pandas.read_csv()`. A type of my data is string with " "(but these strings are numbers indicate the categories). I found that pandas fail to infer strings as `"object"` type, it infer them as `int64`. see the examples below:

*a.csv*:

```
uid, f_1, f_2
1,   "1", 1.1
2,   "2", 2.3
3,   "0", 4.8
```

`pandas.read_csv('a.csv').dtypes` gives the following output:

```
uid:int64
f_1:int64
f_2:float64
```

The type of `f_1` was infered to `'int64'` rather than `'object'`.

However, if I replace all the `"` in a.csv to `'`, then the `f_1` could be correctly infered into `'object'`. How can I prevent the wrong inference without modifying `'a.csv'`? Another question is that why pandas infers strings as `'object'` type rather than `'str'` type?

Comment: For the latter, numpy doesn't have a str type only a str of particular length. Since usually columns are mixed length, pandas uses object for strings for efficiency of data storage. The former might be a bug, please post it on github: https://www.github.com/pydata/pandas/issues

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You can check [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), how site works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need add parameter `skipinitialspace` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

> skipinitialspace : boolean, default False, Skip spaces after delimiter

Test:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io


temp=u"""uid, f_1, f_2
1,  "1", 1.19
2,  "2", 2.3
3,  "0", 4.8"""

print pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp))
   uid    f_1   f_2
0    1    "1"  1.19
1    2    "2"  2.30
2    3    "0"  4.80

#doesn't work dtype    
print pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), dtype= {'f_1': np.int64}).dtypes
uid       int64
 f_1     object
 f_2    float64
dtype: object

print pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), skipinitialspace=True).dtypes
uid      int64
f_1      int64
f_2    float64
dtype: object
```

If you want remove first and last char `"` from column `f_1` use `converters`:

```
import pandas as pd
import io


temp=u"""uid, f_1, f_2
1,  "1", 1.19
2,  "2", 2.3
3,  "0", 4.8"""

print pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp))
   uid    f_1   f_2
0    1    "1"  1.19
1    2    "2"  2.30
2    3    "0"  4.80

#remove "
def converter(x):
    return x.strip('"')

#define each column
converters={'f_1': converter}

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), skipinitialspace=True, converters = converters)
print df
   uid f_1   f_2
0    1   1  1.19
1    2   2  2.30
2    3   0  4.80
print df.dtypes
uid      int64
f_1     object
f_2    float64
dtype: object
```

If you need convert `integer` column  `f_1` to `string` use `dtype`:

```
import pandas as pd
import io


temp=u"""uid, f_1, f_2
1,  1, 1.19
2,  2, 2.3
3,  0, 4.8"""

print pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp)).dtypes
uid       int64
 f_1      int64
 f_2    float64
dtype: object

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), skipinitialspace=True, dtype = {'f_1' : str })

print df
   uid f_1   f_2
0    1   1  1.19
1    2   2  2.30
2    3   0  4.80
print df.dtypes
uid      int64
f_1     object
f_2    float64
dtype: object
```

Notice: Don't forget change `io.StringIO(temp)` to `a.csv`.

And explaining `str` vs `object` is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018654/strings-in-a-dataframe-but-dtype-is-object).

Comment: Thanks for your work! I found it very strange that when I use your tiny samples, it works, but when pandas tries to load a larger file(in my case, 200MB or more), it still failed even if I tried `skipinitialspace=True`. But the `dtype=...` works, so anyway, thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can force inference in the read_csv call by providing a column name or dictionary in the dtype optional parameter, see the pandas documentation on read_csv.