# Cells in a column of pandas dataframe are individual list. dtype list is not working

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

```
dtype_dict = {'_id':str, 'userId':str, 'ownName':str, 'created_time':str, 'created_by':str,
   'addressInputList':list, 'displayName':str, 'emailInputList':list,
   'groupInputList':list, 'imInputList':list, 'lastContactedTime':int,
   'lastUpdatedTime':int, 'noOfTimesContacted':int, 'notes':str, 'orgInputList':list,
   'phoneNumberInputList':list, 'relationInputList':list, 'id':str,
   'inputTakenTime':str}
contacts = pd.read_csv("All-Fri Apr 15 2016 13_45_57 GMT+0530 (IST).csv", dtype=dtype_dict)
print contacts.dtypes
print contacts["phoneNumberInputList"][1]
```

The output I get is this:

[image]

I checked each row of the csv file but the format is uniform in that csv file. That column (phoneNumberInputList) is a correct list in all the rows. Please point out where I am doing mistake and how to read that (and other similar) columns as dtype list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strings in a DataFrame, but dtype is object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018654/strings-in-a-dataframe-but-dtype-is-object)

Comment: That's the way it's supposed to be. Strings are represented as objects (and you can access string methods via `contacts.userId.str`).

Comment: I am facing problem while reading the column named "phoneNumberInputList". I do not know how to read that column as list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is not the correct way but I found a hack. Use graphlab sframe to read the column with dtype as list and then convert that sframe to dataframe with .to_dataframe command.