# pandas: convert multiple columns to string

Tags: string, python-2.7, pandas

I have some columns `['a', 'b', 'c', etc.]` (`a` and `c` are `float64` while `b` is `object`)

I would like to convert all columns to string and preserve `nan`s.

Tried using `df[['a', 'b', 'c']] == df[['a', 'b', 'c']].astype(str)` but that left blanks for the `float64` columns.

Currently I am going through one by one with the following:

```
df['a'] = df['a'].apply(str)
df['a'] = df['a'].replace('nan', np.nan)
```

Is the best way to use `.astype(str)` and then replace `''` with `np.nan`? *Side question: is there a difference between `.astype(str)` and `.apply(str)`?*

**Sample Input:** (dtypes: a=float64, b=object, c=float64)

```
a, b, c, etc.
23, 'a42', 142, etc.
51, '3', 12, etc.
NaN, NaN, NaN, etc.
24, 'a1', NaN, etc.
```

**Desired output:** (dtypes: a=object, b=object, c=object)

```
a, b, c, etc.
'23', 'a42', '142', etc.
'51', 'a3', '12', etc.
NaN, NaN, NaN, etc.
'24', 'a1', NaN, etc.
```

Comment: can you post sample input and desired output data sets?

Comment: @Maxu for sure, I updated the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [23.0, 51.0, np.nan, 24.0],
    'b': ["a42", "3", np.nan, "a1"],
    'c': [142.0, 12.0, np.nan, np.nan]})

for col in df:
    df[col] = [np.nan if (not isinstance(val, str) and np.isnan(val)) else 
               (val if isinstance(val, str) else str(int(val))) 
               for val in df[col].tolist()]

>>> df
     a    b    c
0   23  a42  142
1   51    3   12
2  NaN  NaN  NaN
3   24   a1  NaN

>>> df.values
array([['23', 'a42', '142'],
       ['51', '3', '12'],
       [nan, nan, nan],
       ['24', 'a1', nan]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: thanks! so that basically goes through each column, and leaves a `np.nan` if it is not a string and missing, and otherwise converts the value to string (if i am correct). great! do you know how to get rid of the `.0`s too?

Comment: The columns are converted to floats because of the np.nan.  I'll  add something to convert to ints.

Answer (score 7):

This gives you the list of column names

```py
lst = list(df)
```

This converts all the columns to string type

```py
df[lst] = df[lst].astype(str)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could apply `.astype()` function on every elements of dataframe, or could select the column of interest to convert to string by following ways too.

```
In [41]: df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    ...:     'a': [23.0, 51.0, np.nan, 24.0],
    ...:     'b': ["a42", "3", np.nan, "a1"],
    ...:     'c': [142.0, 12.0, np.nan, np.nan]})
    ...: 

In [42]: 

In [42]: df1
Out[42]: 
      a    b      c
0  23.0  a42  142.0
1  51.0    3   12.0
2   NaN  NaN    NaN
3  24.0   a1    NaN

### Shows current data type of the columns:
In [43]: df1.dtypes
Out[43]: 
a    float64
b     object
c    float64
dtype: object

### Applying .astype() on each element of the dataframe converts the datatype to string
In [45]: df1.astype(str).dtypes
Out[45]: 
a    object
b    object
c    object
dtype: object

### Or, you could select the column of interest to convert it to strings
In [48]: df1[["a", "b", "c"]] = df1[["a","b", "c"]].astype(str)

In [49]: df1.dtypes ### Datatype update
Out[49]: 
a    object
b    object
c    object
dtype: object
```

Comment: Why does df1.astype(str).dtypes show only object types?

Answer (score 0):

I did this way.

get all your value from a specific column, e.g. 'text'.

```
k = df['text'].values
```

then, run each value into a new declared string, e.g. 'thestring'

```
thestring = ""
for i in range(0,len(k)):
    thestring += k[i]
print(thestring)
```

hence, all string in column pandas 'text' has been put into one string variable.

cheers,
fairuz