# pandas how to check dtype for all columns in a dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

It seems that `dtype` only work for `pandas.DataFrame.Series`, right? Is there a function to display data types of all columns at once?

Answer (score 338, accepted):

The **singular** form `dtype` is used to check the data type for a single column. And the ***plural*** form `dtypes` is for data frame which returns data types for all columns. Essentially:

***For a single column***:

```
dataframe.column.dtype
```

***For all columns***:

```
dataframe.dtypes
```

*Example*:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [True, False, False], 'C': ['a', 'b', 'c']})

df.A.dtype
# dtype('int64')
df.B.dtype
# dtype('bool')
df.C.dtype
# dtype('O')

df.dtypes
#A     int64
#B      bool
#C    object
#dtype: object
```

Comment: If you want all the non-numeric/categorical columns you can get it by 
`df.dtypes[df.dtypes != 'int64'][df.dtypes != 'float64']`

Comment: Can you please explain why column C is having an object type instead of str?

Comment: @StarRider see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018654/strings-in-a-dataframe-but-dtype-is-object) as well as the [`pandas` documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/basics.html#dtypes) where it mentions: "_Pandas uses the object dtype for storing strings_"

Comment: Any idea why I have object as dtype?

Comment: I hadn't realized that equality is a bit fuzzy with dtypes.  `df.C.dtype` returns `dtype('O')`, but `df.C.dtype=='object'` is true.

Answer (score 29):

Suppose df is a pandas DataFrame then to get number of non-null values and data types of all column at once use:

```
df.info()
```

Comment: Correct, but it will give summary only. Not detail of all columns.

Answer (score 14):

To go one step further, I assume you actually want to do something with these dtypes.
`df.dtypes.to_dict()` comes in handy.

```py
my_type = 'float64'

dtypes = dataframe.dtypes.to_dict()

for col_name, typ in dtypes.items():
    if (typ != my_type): #<---
        raise ValueError(f"Yikes - `dataframe['{col_name}'].dtype == {typ}` not {my_type}")
```

You'll find that Pandas did a really good job comparing NumPy classes and user-provided strings. For example: even things like `'double' == dataframe['col_name'].dtype` will succeed when `.dtype==np.float64`.

Answer (score 11):

(*This answer does not directly answer OP's question but might be useful.*)

Responses so far rely on printed reports or string values, so might not be future-proof.

pandas offers [programmatic ways](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/arrays.html?highlight=utility#utilities) for type checking:

```py
import pandas as pd
from pandas.api.types import is_object_dtype, is_numeric_dtype, is_bool_dtype
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [True, False, False], 'C': ['a', 'b', 'c']})

is_numeric_dtype(df['A'])
>>> True
```

Answer (score 8):

If you have a lot many columns and you do `df.info()` or `df.dtypes` it may give you overall statistics of columns or just some columns from the top and bottom like

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

Int64Index: 4387 entries, 1 to 4387

Columns: 119 entries, 
CoulmnA to ColumnZ

dtypes: datetime64[ns(24), 
float64(54), object(41)

memory usage: 4.0+ MB
```

It just gives that 24 columns are datetime, 54 are float64 and 41 are object.

So, if you want the datatype of each column in one command, do:

`dict(df.dtypes)`

Answer (score 1):

You can also see it indirectly by using dataframe_name.column_name which shows column values and also dtype with it.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {"strings" : ["a","b","c"], "ints" : [1,2,3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df.strings)
print("------------")
print(df.ints)
```

which will output:

```
0    a
1    b
2    c
Name: strings, dtype: object
------------
0    1
1    2
2    3
Name: ints, dtype: int64
```