How to convert string scientific notation to float within a txt file
I have code in a .txt file that has scientific notation values stored as strings and I am trying to convert them to floats that way I can perform calculations on them. However, when I try to attempt this all the values get converted to NaN.
Original Code:
'''sandbox for testing'''

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Load the data
# Use the appropriate delimiter for your data, e.g., "\t" for tab-separated values
data_Test = pd.read_csv("TestData5.txt", header=None, delimiter="\t", dtype=str)



print the first few rows
z = data_Test
print("TestData (first 5 rows):\n", z.head())

output:
TestData (first 5 rows):
                                                    0
0     7.9000000e+00   6.0000000e-01   6.0000000e-...
1     7.5000000e+00   5.0000000e-01   3.6000000e-...
2     7.8000000e+00   6.1000000e-01   2.9000000e-...
3     8.5000000e+00   2.8000000e-01   5.6000000e-...
4     8.1000000e+00   5.6000000e-01   2.8000000e-...

What I tried:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
 


'''WHERE THE ISSUE LIES '''
# Convert all values to float in TestData
data_Test = pd.read_csv("TestData5.txt", header=None, delimiter="\t")
data_Test = data_Test.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
z = data_Test


# Print the first few rows to verify the conversion
print("TestData (first 5 rows):\n", z[:5])

output:
TestData (first 5 rows):
     0
0 NaN
1 NaN
2 NaN
3 NaN
4 NaN
TrainData shape: (1119, 11)
TrainLabels shape: (1119,)
TestData shape: (480, 1)


Add a sample of the input data please so the question becomes a [mcve]. BTW, numbers are probably already float and scientific notation it's just the representation. Try print(data_Test.some_column.dtypes) -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/40353394/2834978

@n00bcoder_24, So if the value was 7.9000000e+310, you would want to change that "79000 (about 300  more zeros) 000000.0"?

Here may have extra spaces when you read numeric data from the TestData5.txt file that can not be removed automatically using pd.read_csv function.
you  can try : data_Test = pd.read_csv("TestData5.txt", header=None, delimiter="\t", skipinitialspace=True) to remove extra space.
Then use data_Test = data_Test.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce'). I hope it will work.

I found delim_whitespace and astype(float) to be working. Is this what you are looking for?
data_Test = pd.read_csv("TestData.txt", header=None, delim_whitespace=True)
data_Test = data_Test.astype(float)
print("TestData (first 5 rows):\n", data_Test[:5])

Output
    0     1     2
0   7.9   0.60  0.060
1   7.5   0.50  0.036
2   7.8   0.61  0.029
3   8.5   0.28  0.056
4   8.1   0.56  0.028

TestData.txt
7.9000000e+00   6.0000000e-01  6.0000000e-02
7.5000000e+00    5.0000000e-01   3.6000000e-02
7.8000000e+00    6.1000000e-01   2.9000000e-02
8.5000000e+00    2.8000000e-01   5.6000000e-02
8.1000000e+00    5.6000000e-01   2.8000000e-02

