# find which row has a string

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas and I have a column that has numbers but when I check for datatype I get the column is an object. I think one of the rows in that column is actually a string. How can I find out which row is the string? For example:

```
Name    A    B
John    0    1
Rich    1    0
Jim     O    1
```

Jim has the letter "O" instead of zero on column A.  what can I use in pandas to find which row has the string instead of the number if I have thousands of rows? In this example I used the letter O, but it could be any letter, really.

Comment: `object` means that it holds generic Python-typed values, which can be any type Python knows—an `int`, a `str`, a `list` of `set`s of some custom `namedtuple` type that you created, whatever. And you can just call methods on those objects (e.g., via Pandas' `apply`) the same way you do with any other Python variables.

Comment: Related: [Strings in a DataFrame, but dtype is object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018654/strings-in-a-dataframe-but-dtype-is-object)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas.to_numeric` to see what doesn't get converted to a number. Then with `.isnull()` you can subset your original `df` to see exactly which rows are the problematic ones.

```
import pandas as pd
df[pd.to_numeric(df.A, errors='coerce').isnull()]
#  Name  A  B
#2  Jim  O  1
```

If you're not sure which column is problematic, you could so something like (assuming you want to check everything other than the 1st name column):

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
for col in df.columns[1::]:
    df2[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col], errors='coerce')

df[df2.isnull().sum(axis=1).astype(bool)]
#  Name  A  B
#2  Jim  O  1
```

Answer (score 0):

The dtype `object` means that the column holds generic Python-typed values.

Those values can be any type Python knows—an `int`, a `str`, a `list` of `set`s of some custom `namedtuple` type that you created, whatever.

And you can just call normal Python functions or methods on those objects (e.g., by accessing them directly, or via Pandas' `apply`) the same way you do with any other Python variables.

And that includes the `type` function, the `isinstance` function, etc.:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 'O'], 'B': [1, 0, 1]})
>>> df.A
0    0
1    1
2    O
Name: A, dtype: object
>>> df.A.apply(type)
0    <class 'int'>
1    <class 'int'>
2    <class 'str'>
Name: A, dtype: object
>>> df.A.apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))
0    False
1    False
2     True
Name: A, dtype: bool
>>>  df.A.apply(repr)
0      0
1      1
2    'O'
Name: A, dtype: object
```

… and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add another **very short and concise** solution which would be a combination of ALollz and abarnert.

First let's find all columns that are of type object with `cols = (df.dtypes == 'object').nonzero()[0]`. Let us filter those out using `iloc` and apply `pd.to_numeric` (and let us also not include the name column using a slice of the col variable `[1:]`). Then we check for `na-values` and if `any(1)` (row-wise) then we return back the index of that row.

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = '''\
Name    A    B   C
John    0    1   O
Rich    1    0   2
Jim     O    1   O'''

df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data), sep='\s+')

cols = (df.dtypes == 'object').nonzero()[0]
rows = df.iloc[:,cols[1:]].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').isna().any(1).nonzero()[0]
print(rows)
```

Returns:

```
[0 2]  # <-- Means that row 0 and 2 contain N/A-values in at least 1 column
```

This answers your question: `what can I use in pandas to find which row has the string instead of the number` but for all columns looking for strings by assuming they can't be converted to numbers with pd.to_numeric.

Answer (score 0):

```
types = list(df['A'].apply(lambda x: type(x)))
names = list(df['Name'])
d = dict(zip(names, types))
```

This will give you a dictionary of `{name:type}` so you know which name has a string value in column A. Alternatively, if you just want to find the row the string is on, use this:

```
types = list(df['A'].apply(lambda x: type(x)))
rows = df.index.tolist()
d = dict(zip(rows, types))
# to get only the rows that have string values in column A
d = {k:v for k,v in d.items() if v == str}
```