# How can I have different types in Pandas Series if Pandas Series uses numpy?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

As far as I know numpys [ndarrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html#numpy.dtype) element must be of same type and pandas series uses [ndarray](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html) to hold values. But it seems like I am able to append an integer to a Series that holds string.

Sample code I have..

```
import pandas as pd

sr = pd.Series(['foo'])
sr = sr.append(pd.Series([1], index=[1]))
print(type(sr.values))
print(sr.values.dtype)
print(type(sr.iloc[0]))
print(type(sr.iloc[1]))
```

and the output:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
object
<class 'str'>
<class 'int'>
```

If the ndarrays type is object, how come int is returned for the item at index loc 1?

Comment: In an object dtype array, the elements retain their Python type, str, int, etc.  As with a list, such an array contains pointers to objects stored elsewhere in memory.  Don't confuse `dtype` and `type`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An `object` dtype series consists of pointers to arbitrary Python objects. Think of `object` dtype in the same way as you might a Python list. For example, the Python list `['foo', 1]` does not store values in a contiguous memory block.

In the same way you can't attach a specific *data type* to `list`, even if all elements are of the same type, a Pandas `object` series contains pointers to any number of types.

In general, Pandas dtype changes to *accommodate* values. So adding a float value to an integer series will turn the whole series to `float`. Adding a string to a numeric series will force the series to `object`. You can even force a numeric series to have `object` dtype, though this is not recommended:

```
s = pd.Series(list(range(100000)), dtype=object)
```

The main benefit of Pandas, i.e. vectorised computations, is lost as soon as you start using `object` series. These should be *avoided* where possible. You can, for example, use `pd.Categorical` to factorise categories if applicable.

Here's a trivial example demonstrating the performance drop:

```
t = pd.Series(list(range(100000)))

%timeit s*10  # 7.31 ms
%timeit t*10  # 366 µs
```

Related: [Strings in a DataFrame, but dtype is object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018654/strings-in-a-dataframe-but-dtype-is-object)

Comment: `In general, Pandas dtype changes to accommodate values. ` You mean pandas changes dtype of the ndarray?

Comment: @KorayTugay, Yes. Or creates a new array with another dtype, and attaches this to a dataframe column/series label.