# Difference between drop and select_dtypes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

What is the difference between these two methods to delete a row if the string 'something' is found in the column 'search'?

First method:

```
mydata = mydata.set_index("search")
mydata = mydata.drop("something", axis=0)
```

This method seems pretty straight forward and is understandable.

Second method:

```
mydata = mydata[~mydata.select_dtypes(['object']).eq('something').any(1)]
```

I don't really know how this method works. Where in this line is it specified to drop/delete the row? And why does it work with 'object' instead of 'search'? What does the "~" stand for? I just can't find it in the documentation.

Comment: I think I got it - more or less. "select_dtypes" searches for all rows with the string 'something' in the column and keeps them. The "~" reverses this statement.

Comment: No, that's incorrect, `select_dtypes` subsets your dataframe by series/column **type**. The subsequent method `eq` is the one that tests for equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two methods are **not** identical. Let's look at the second method in parts.

#### Step 1: subset dataframe via `select_dtypes`

`mydata.select_dtypes(['object'])` filters your dataframe for only series with `object` dtype. You can extract the dtype of each series via `mydata.dtypes`. Typically, non-numeric series will have `object` dtype, which indicates a sequence of pointers, similar to `list`.

In this case, your two methods only align when series `search` is the only `object` dtype series.

#### Step 2: Test for equality via `eq`

Since Step 1 returns a *dataframe*, even if it only contains one series, `pd.DataFrame.eq` will return a dataframe of Boolean values.

#### Step 3: Test for any `True` value row-wise via `any`

Next your second method checks if any value is `True` row-wise (`axis=1`). Again, if your only `object` series is `search`, then this equates to the same as your first method.

If you have multiple `object` series, then your two methods may not align, as a row may be excluded due to *another* series being equal to `'something'`.

Comment: Thanks. The big missing piece was that 'object' is a data type (str). Others would be 'int', 'float' and 'bool'. And just a little bonus question: 'object' can be mixed type?

Comment: Yes, see [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21020411/9209546) to understand what `object` really means.