# Why the type of pd.DataFrame every items is float, but the dtype of pd.DataFrame is object?

Tags: python, pandas, types, series

results_table is a pd.DataFrame

When I

```
print(type(results_table.loc[0,'Mean recall score']))
```

it return

```
<class 'numpy.float64'>
```

Every items is `float`

But when I

```
print(results_table['Mean recall score'].dtype)
```

it returns

```
object
```

Why is there such behavior?

Comment: There are some scenarios where every item in a series is a float but the `dtype` is `object`. For example, some error when reading from file that was coerced; or when you had mixed types (e.g. floats and strings) and substituted the strings with other floats at a later time; etc. Just use `pd.to_numeric(df['score'])` or `.astype(float)` directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note `df.loc[0, x]` only considers the value in row label `0` and column label `x`, *not* your entire dataframe. Now let's consider an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1.5, 'hello', 'test', 2]}, dtype=object)

print(type(df.loc[0, 'A']))  # type of single element in series

# <class 'float'>

print(df['A'].dtype)         # type of series

# object
```

As you can see, an `object` dtype series can hold arbitrary Python objects. You can even, if you wish, extract the type of each element of your series:

```
print(df['A'].map(type))

# 0    <class 'float'>
# 1      <class 'str'>
# 2      <class 'str'>
# 3      <class 'int'>
# Name: A, dtype: object
```

An `object` dtype series is simply a collection of pointers to various objects *not* held in a contiguous memory block, as may be the case with numeric series. This is comparable to Python `list` and explains why performance is poor when you work with `object` instead of numeric series.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21020411/9209546) for a visual respresentation of the above.

Answer (score 0):

In the first print statement you are slicing out one single element from you dataframe. This single item you are looking at is a float.

In the second print statement you are actually pulling out a pandas series (ie you are pulling out the whole column) and printing the type of that.

The pandas series is an object, but each entry in the series is a float. So this is why you get the results you did.