# Pandas Dataframe elements defined to be of 'object'-type are actually 'int'

Tags: python, pandas

In my daily work with Pandas, I often have to set the type of IDs as 'object'. To best illustrate the problem I write down the simple yet puzzling code:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'A':[12,32,34,54,65],'B':[122,32,234,54,65],'C':[12,323,34,544,653]},dtype='object')
```

If I check the types of the columns:

```
In: a.dtypes
```

I get as expected

```
Out: A    object
     B    object
     C    object
     dtype: object
```

However, the type of a single element is surprising to me:

```
In: type(a.A.values[0])

Out: int
```

This is problematic if I try to merge two DataFrames: If the key is not of the same type they will not match (123456 does not match with '123456').

After some work I get the DataFrame to behave in the way I would have expected (for more details, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/change-data-type-of-columns-in-pandas%EF%BC%9F)). This is done by doing:

```
b = pd.DataFrame({'A':[12,32,34,54,65],'B':[122,32,234,54,65],'C':[12,323,34,544,653]}).astype(str)
```

Why does the statement "dtype='object'" is not enough to get string elements. Am I missing something?

Comment: @jpp I do not agree with you about the fact that my question is a duplicate. I already knew both pages you suggested. But I am here asking why Pandas behaves like this and not how to convert the columns. My last line of code gave already the answer about how to convert a column from integer to string

Comment: There are 2 duplicates marked. The first answers "why", the second answers "how to resolve". Look at the chart [in the first question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21020411/9209546). Nobody in 5 years has come up with a clearer answer, I don't think they'll be able to today.

Comment: @jpp: may I ask you to kindly remove the second link (the one concerning the solution to the problem): as I already pointed out, I put already the solution to my problem into the question. If you think that this can help some readers I can edit my question to include your link.

Comment: @jpp: Concerning your comment about the first link: look at the answer of Saket Kumar Singh: concise, well-documented and direct to the point. I would say that in 5 years we did get a clearer answer, at least for me, physicist without a PhD in CS

Comment: Yes, great answer, but here on SO we try and collect answers to the same question so that users can *see them side-by-side*. Ideally, he should have posted it on the duplicate post.

Comment: 'object' is short for "an arbitrary Python type (different than numpy-pandas specific types)". This might be a string, this might be an int, a decimal or some other funny class you defined yourself. When you use `dtype=object` (or `.astype(object)`), pandas either preserves the Python type (a Python int, in your example) or converts to a Python type (from np.int64 to Python int for example). Mixed dtypes are not actually an issue here because all your elements are integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Pandas' documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#basics-dtypes):

> If a pandas object contains data with multiple dtypes in a single column, the dtype of the column will be chosen to accommodate all of the data types (object is the most general)

Since `object` accommodates all data types, it wouldn't be coercing your `int` values to `str`

Also

> The values attribute on a DataFrame return the lower-common-denominator of the dtypes, meaning the dtype that can accommodate ALL of the types in the resulting homogeneous dtyped NumPy array

Further proof that `object` dtype is the lower-common-denominator and was hence returned and also could not enforce your `int` to `str`

Answer (score 0):

`values()` is an inbuilt method in Python programming language that returns a list of all the values available in a given dictionary.

Returns:

returns a list of all the values available in a given dictionary.

In your case, Values() returned some values, for that value you are using Type function,

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'A':"dd",'B':[122,32,234,54,65],'C':[12,323,34,544,653]},dtype='object')



c = a.A.values[0]



type(c)
```

Ouput : str