# Set two columns as tuple index in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

Suppose I have a pandas dataframe with columns 0, 1 and 'Future Connections'. How do I set columns 0 and 1 as one tuple index:

For example this data frame:

```
0   1        Future Connection
6   840      0.0
4   197      1.0
620 979      0.0
```

would result to:

```
0           Future Connection
(6, 840)    0.0
(4, 197)    1.0
(620, 979)  0.0
```

Comment: Why not use a multi-level index as recommended by jpp?

Comment: It's what I want though. But it's what the course I'm studying in Coursera wanted to be returned to get some points.

Comment: @Nikko, You should write to Coursera explaining that they are not teaching Pandas *as it should be taught*. This is a classic misuse of Pandas.

Comment: @jpp Hahaha. The subject is about NetworkX in Python. The two columns were set of nodes. Then it's passed to ML to predict unlabeled set of 'nodes'. In this case, it was predicting the probability of two employees of having a 'future connection'. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use list comprehension with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract column `0, 1`:

```
print (df.columns)
Index([0, 1, 'Future Connection'], dtype='object')

df.index = [x for x in zip(df.pop(0), df.pop(1))]
print (df)
            Future Connection
(6, 840)                  0.0
(4, 197)                  1.0
(620, 979)                0.0
```

Comment: This is such an elegant answer.  Once again I have learned from jezrael.

Comment: Thank you again! You are really one of the best!

Answer (score 5):

> How do I set columns 0 and 1 as one tuple index:

"Tuple index" as a concept does not exist in Pandas. You can have an `object` dtype index containing tuples, but this isn't recommended. The best option is to use a `MultiIndex`, which stores underlying values efficiently via NumPy arrays. Indeed, Pandas facilitates this with [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df = df.set_index([0, 1])

print(df)
#          Future Connection
# 0   1                     
# 6   840                0.0
# 4   197                1.0
# 620 979                0.0

print(df.index)
# MultiIndex(levels=[[4, 6, 620], [197, 840, 979]],
#            labels=[[1, 0, 2], [1, 0, 2]],
#            names=[0, 1])

print(df.index.values)
# [(6, 840) (4, 197) (620, 979)]
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Data is just from Coursera. I just followed.

Comment: @Nikko, I'm not surprised, there are a multitude of ways Pandas can be misused. This is just one of them. Pity it's in a course, though.

Comment: @jpp, or anyone who cares to pipe in, I'm glad you demonstrated MultiIndex, but I'm curious why using tuples to index is a misuse. What is the drawback? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @KalebCoberly, See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21020411/9209546) and the first comment to that answer regarding inefficiency of using `object` dytpe.

Comment: @jpp, thanks for that. So the issue is that MultiIndex is more efficient, not that using tuples for an index is buggy or anything? It's just not as efficient?

Comment: @KalebCoberly, Correct: not buggy, but inefficient and not recommended.