# Access a list within a dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I'm working on dataframes with PANDAS in Python. I read a csv file with `pandas.read_csv(...)`. In this csv file the column `'possible_stops'` contains lists (each cells in this column looks like : `[ ]` or `[str0,str1]`).

I want to iterate over the rows with `itertuples()` and for each row i want to access the list inside `'possible_stops'` column. 
However, the dtype of this column is `object` and when i look for the type of a specific cell (`type(row.possible_stops)`) it returns `str`. I think there is something to do with `dtype = ..` inside the `read_csv` method but i don't exactly know what to do.

How can i convert cells inside this column into lists ?

Thanks very much!

EDIT :
the resulting df looks like :

```
latitude longitude gps_speed possible_stops    
1.05869 1574942547  0.0 [['Bapeaume', 2]]
1.05862 1573910439  0.0 [['Bapeaume', 2]]
1.05862 1573910441  0.0 [['Bapeaume', 2]]
1.05862 1573910443  0.0 [['Bapeaume', 2]]
1.05862 1573910445  0.0 [['Bapeaume', 2]]
1.05862 1573910447  0.0 [['Bapeaume', 2]]
```

Comment: `object` is not strictly a dtype (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21020411/7685544)). Can you supply an example of your data? I think it should be possible to access the lists inside the column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to convert the cells into lists with `ast.literal_eval()`

```
for row in selection_traces.itertuples():
l=ast.literal_eval(row.possible_stops)
```

The problem has been already solved on this forum... Sorry and thanks you !

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible for an item in a column in a Pandas dataframe to have the data type 'list'. See a list of possible datatypes for a dataframe column here: https://pbpython.com/pandas_dtypes.html.

So instead of it having the type 'list' when stored in a dataframe a list is inserted as a string object. 
However, it is still possible to enter the items in the lists in the dataframe with a double for-loop. For example to print each item:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'possible_stops':[['str0', 'str1'], ['str2', 'str3']], 'Age':[[20, 21], [19, 18]]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
for row in df.itertuples():
    for item in row.possible_stops:
        print(item)
```

This will print the names in the created dataset one by one.