# Types of all columns are 'int64' but pandas.DataFrame type is still object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas.DataFrame of size `[200 rows x 200 columns]`. Although all columns are of type `int64`, **the type of DataFrame** seems to be `object`. Why is that?

```
d.shape
Out[70]: (200, 200)

d.dtypes
Out[66]: 
      variable
edge  0           int64
      1           int64
      2           int64
      3           int64
      4           int64
                  ...
      195         int64
      196         int64
      197         int64
      198         int64
      199         int64
Length: 200, dtype: object

(d.dtypes == "int64").all()
Out[68]: True
```

The same situation can be observed in below toy example,

```
a = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(4,4)))

a
Out[91]: 
   0  1  2  3
0  0  1  0  0
1  0  0  1  0
2  0  1  0  1
3  1  1  1  1

a.dtypes
Out[92]: 
0    int64
1    int64
2    int64
3    int64
dtype: object
```

The answer of [Strings in a DataFrame, but dtype is object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018654/strings-in-a-dataframe-but-dtype-is-object) says:

> Every element in a ndarray must has the same size in byte. For int64
> and float64, they are 8 bytes. But for strings, the length of the
> string is not fixed. So instead of save the bytes of strings in the
> ndarray directly, Pandas use object ndarray, which save pointers to
> objects, because of this the dtype of this kind ndarray is object.

But here, all columns are all `int64`. I also couldn't find a way to convert that `object` to `int64` or should I?

Comment: if that truly represents the type of the DataFrame, that does make sense. the DataFrame itself is an object. but it's definitely a little confusing.

Comment: as I understand, dtype always becomes ´object´ for pandas.DataFrame, even all columns are of same type. It gives true dtype only for a single column which is pandas.Series.