# dataframe string type cannot use replace method

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['asdf']}, dtype="string")
df["a"].replace({"a":"b"}, regex=True)

not chagend

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['asdf']}, dtype="object")
df["a"].replace({"a":"b"}, regex=True)

changed
```

I want to convert string value to other.
but, if I use type string, I could not use replace method.
how to chage string type data?
should I use object type?

Comment: I tried the first code and it worked; changed the a to b. pandas version 1.3

Comment: afternoon_drinker,  you need to use `.str` method on string `dtype`, see the answer for more details.

Comment: @sammywemmy, thank you. I used 1.2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see the difference by checking with `df.dtypes` it's evident that you r datatype is ultimately is an `object` but column is only string hence you need to apply `pandas.Series.str.replace` to get your results.

However, when you choose `dtype="object"` your both `dtype` and column data remains `object` thus you don't need to use `.str` converion.

Please check the [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.3.2/pandas/core/strings/accessor.py#L1229-L1404), which explains it well:

> *For calling `.str.{method}` on a Series or Index, it is necessary to
> first
> initialize the :class:`StringMethods` object, and then call the method.*

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['asdf']}, dtype="string")
>>> df
      a
0  asdf

>>> df.dtypes
a    string
dtype: object

>>> df["a"].str.replace("a", "b", regex=True)
0    bsdf
Name: a, dtype: string
```

- 

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['asdf']}, dtype="object")
>>> df.dtypes
a    object
dtype: object
```

### dtype:

browned from @HYRY.

Look at here [source of inspiration for below explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018654/strings-in-a-dataframe-but-dtype-is-object)

From pandas docs where [All dtypes can now be converted to StringDtype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v1.1.0.html#all-dtypes-can-now-be-converted-to-stringdtype)

The `dtype` object comes from NumPy, it describes the type of element in a `ndarray`. Every element in an `ndarray` must have the same size in bytes. For `int64` and `float64`, they are 8 bytes. But for strings, the length of the string is not fixed. So instead of saving the bytes of strings in the `ndarray` directly, Pandas uses an object `ndarray`, which saves pointers to objects; because of this the `dtype` of this kind `ndarray` is object.

Here is an example:

- the int64 array contains 4 int64 value.
- the object array contains 4 pointers to 3 string objects.

[image]

### Note:

*Object dtype have a much broader scope. They can not only include strings, but also any other data that Pandas doesn't understand.*

Comment: thank you. Which type is better to use for string operations?

Answer (score 0):

For the string type you can do this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['asdf']}, dtype="string")
df["a"].str.replace("a","b")
```

Comment: thank you. how to do in case of df["a"].replace({"a":"b"}, regex=False)