# Why does Pandas ignore the data type numpy.str_?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to create a Series object and specify `dtype=np.str_` but looks the type is ignored by Pandas.

I tried to apply the method **astype** but I have the same result:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s1 = pd.Series(["t1", "t2"], dtype=np.str_)

print(type(s1[0]))  # <class 'str'>
print(type(s1.astype(np.str_)[0]))  # <class 'str'>
```

If I replace it with `dtype=np.bytes_` or create the object using the code `pd.Series([np.str_("t1"), np.str_("t2")])`, it works as expected:

```
s2 = pd.Series(["t1", "t2"], dtype=np.bytes_)
s3 = pd.Series([np.str_("t1"), np.str_("t2")])

print(type(s2[0]))  # <class 'numpy.bytes_'>
print(type(s3[0]))  # <class 'numpy.str_'>
```

Comment: because pandas doesn't really use the numpy str types, and instead uses `object` by default (you could also use `pd.StringDtype()` nowadays, not sure how stable that is currently). For what reason do you want to use `np.str_`?

Comment: furthermore, since Pandas 2.0, there is also the option to use Arrow datatypes

Comment: I am learning Pandas and I am trying to explicitly use the Numpy data type np.str_ as described in the pandas reference doc. In our case, the type of the elements is str, not object. pd.StringDtype() is a data type extension in Pandas.

Comment: So, you *have* no reason really? In pandas, `object` is the type used for a string data type. The extension types, and arrow types (in pandas >= 2.0) are your other option. What reference are you referring to, exactly?

Comment: I have no reason to use the numpy type. I just want to understand why Pandas only ignores numpy.str_. There is any problem with numpy.int8, numpy.float64, numpy.bytes_ and so on. The question is not related to the extension and pyarrow types.

Comment: I don't know how to explain this to you any more clearly - it defaults to `object` when you pass `np.str_` for the same reason it defaults to `object` when you pass it `str`, because **pandas doesn't use the numpy string types**. Prior to pandas 2.0, it used *only* `object` if you indicate the column/series should be some sort of string type. Notice, all the dtype's of your series are `object`. perhaps you can add the reference you are following so that we can understand the context of your question better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward answer to your question is that `pandas` only supports the following text types:

- `object`
- `pandas.StringDtype()`

This is explicitly stated in the [user guide here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/text.html#text-data-types)

This is why if you pass `str`, it defaults to `object`:

```
>>> pd.Series([1, "foo"], dtype=str)
0      1
1    foo
dtype: object
```

Indeed, if you look in the guts of the pandas wrappers for `astype`, you see this in the [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/58b1d12ee975ec6ad63ad8ec5ce3434d6ea7163e/pandas/core/dtypes/astype.py#L184):

```
# in pandas we don't store numpy str dtypes, so convert to object
if isinstance(dtype, np.dtype) and issubclass(values.dtype.type, str):
    values = np.array(values, dtype=object)
```

Comment: As I understand object is a general pointer to elements which can have different data types but each element must have own data type. The argument dtype allows us to specify an explicit type when we create pandas objects or use the method astype. It might be Numpy, Python, Pandas, PyArrow data types. You can find a good explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018654/strings-in-a-dataframe-but-dtype-is-object. But it's still not clear why numpy.str_ is ignored.

Comment: *Because Pandas does not support any type for text other than `object` or `pandas.StringDtype()`*. What is it you do not understand, exactly? I've even shown you exactly in the source code where the `np.str_` dtype is *converted to `object`*, and I've explained to you *why* this happens, because according to `pandas` own documentation, `object` and `pandas.StringDtype()` are the only text types supported (unless you are using Arrow)